# does read() in c read null character

Tags: c, serial-port, java-native-interface

I have written program to read from usb port (which is not connected to anything) .From java I am passing int filedescriptor and byte array and in jni I am converting byte array to char* and using read().

```
jbyte *bufferPtr2 = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, buf, NULL);  
unsigned char* d_data2 = (unsigned char*)bufferPtr2;    
n = read(fd, d_data2, lengthOfArray);
```

After executing , n=1 but d_data2 is empty. Why is this? Does read() read null character as data?

Comment: What is `lengthOfArray`? And define "empty" in terms of `d_data2` - the fact  that `read` returned 1 shows that it contained 1 byte

Comment: lengthofArray is 100. When is use "evaluate expression" in android studio during debugging d_data2 contains '\0'

Comment: It's binary data, not a string so it's not actually empty - it contains a `\0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [the POSIX documentation for `read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html):

> The `read()` function shall attempt to read `nbyte` bytes from the file associated with the open file descriptor, `fildes`, into the buffer pointed to by `buf`.

The actual value of the bytes that are read does not matter.

So yes, `read()` will read `NUL` bytes.